# Where to put Erlang code of the module used for dynamic substitution in Tsung

Tags: erlang, performance-testing, ubuntu-18.04, tsung

I'm starting with tsung and i'm following the user manual to do the tests, ut I can't find where to put my module for dynamic substitution.

The [documentation](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-advanced-features.html#dynamic-substitutions) say:

> Use erlc to compiled the code, and put the resulting .beam file in
>   $PREFIX/lib/erlang/lib/tsung-X.X.X/ebin/ on all client machines.

I can't find the directory it refers to. I tried using `whereis` and seeing the directories that appear for tsung and earlang, but found nothing similar either.

My Current OS is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

And I installed erlang and dependencies like this:

`apt-get install erlang-ssl erlang-xmerl zlib1g-dev esl-erlang`

And Tsung like this ( after downloading and unzipping from [here](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/dist/), tsung-1.7.0.tar.gz ):

`./configure && make && make install`

Comment: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tsung-1.7.0/ebin?

Comment: No, I dont have `/usr/local/lib/erlang`. My whereis return `erlang: /usr/lib/erlang` only.

Comment: Why are you using whereis to find directories? See ls and find.

Comment: Yes... I'm stupid... `sudo find / -path /mnt -prune -o -name "tsung"`, show other list of paths, I'll try this list.